# Is the 3dB turnover and 45° correspondence only valid for low pass filter transfer function?

Tags: decibel

I have been reading at some systems that at 3dB point the phase shift becomes 45°. But is this fact only valid for low pass filters?

Comment: Perhaps you mean -3 dB **attenuation** and 45° **phase shift**. The -3 dB point is **by definition** the cutoff point. Only a **1st order lowpass** filter will have 45° phase **lag** at its cutoff point. A **1st order high pass** filter will have -45° phase **lead** at the -3 dB point. Higher order filters (2nd order and more) will have more phase shift at their cutoff points.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie do you want to make than an answer?